# AUD straight to Monero

Tags: currency-conversion, fiat

I'm new to the community - just wondering if there are any ways to purchase Monero with AUD? (Australian dollars) Any exchanges offering? What do you think the chances of them offering it in the next 12 months are? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

Lacking a direct answer, the fastest 2 step option is to buy bitcoin and then use https://shapeshift.io to trade bitcoin for monero.

http://poloniex.com might give you a better price than shapeshift and you can buy much more as shapeshift's limits are small. You still have to have bitcoin first and send it to poloniex.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one [Australian exchange](https://altcoins.com.au) which was [announced several months ago on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4rnl1k/i_have_added_monero_to_my_australian_exchange/).

According to [their website](https://altcoins.com.au/buy/xmr):

> Using the form above enter the amount of Monero you want to buy or the amount of Australian dollars you want to spend along with the wallet address to send the coins to and click on 'Buy Now' to complete the payment.
>
> The payment is easily completed online in minutes by POLi Payments a business from Australia Post and after payment is complete the coins will be sent to your wallet address immediately.
>
> If you don't have your own wallet you can sign up for a free account using the 'Register' button at the top of the page to create a free online Monero wallet. You can withdraw your XMR from the online wallet at any time and without fees.

Comment: As of November 10th, 2016, buying Monero is disabled on the website.